# POST with guzzle returns 417

Tags: php, post, guzzle

I created an API to post JSON data to another API, but for some JSON it returns 417 error code.

I checked these JSONs and tried to re-post them, but i got the 417 again, the post is only working if i delete some values from the JSON.

The JSONs is always valid and it's around 1.5KB of data, but i cant figure it out why it's happening.

Guzzle version: 7.0, PHP version: 7.4

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'verify' => false,
    'expect' => false
]);

$request = null;

$request = $guzzle->post(
    $request_url,
    [
        'auth' => [self::$API_USERNAME, self::$API_PASSWORD],
        'json' => [$request_body]
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a postman request and send the invalid JSON to the API direct without the middleware, now i can see the full error related to the invalid email address format.